# Show Bootstrap tooltip when click on CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I use CKEDITOR for my website. It's work well. But I want to show a tooltip when user click on CKEDITOR. I tried use Bootstrap tooltip, it worked in another text field, but didn't work on CKEDITOR field.

My website use Jquery 1.9.3, Bootstrap

I tried this code in another field, it worked well

**HTML**

```
<div id = "abcde" data-original-title = "aaaa">abcd</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#abcde").tooltip('show')
```

And I do the same with CKEDITOR field, nothing happened. Please help, thanks!

*UPDATE*
I just added my **jsfiddle** code 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZSBLR/19/
It's too slow, try to refresh sometimes.

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle pls

Comment: I just added jsfiddle, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely need to use the `selector` option when loading your tooltip.

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: "#cke_job_description",
    title: "This is a test"
});
```

Any element dynamically added with the ID or class you specify will then have a tooltip applied to it.

[Here is the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSBLR/21/)

Comment: Please see my jsfiddle code. I tried your code but it didn't work

Comment: Oh, It really worked. 
But If I try popover method instead tooltip method, it doesn't work any more. Could you help me, many thanks!